# Magento 1.9 customer account navigation missing from left column

Tags: magento-1.9

My issue is when i login to my live magento website the account navigation sidebar is missing from the left column of the my Account page, however when i login the same website in my local system(using XAMPP) the sidebar is showing there and its working fine.

i already tried this

```
<layout version="1.0">
<default><remove name="left"/></default>
```

i have removed this

```
<remove name="left"/>
```

but its not working please help.

Comment: According to your code, left sidebar will be removed. Depends upon on which handler you have written this code. Can you update you full xml file?